# Global hostlister only works for 3rd party component if an element with the selector is in my component

Tags: angular

I have a component that controls embedded an 3rd party component. Lets say MyPartenComponent

```html
<div dependency-id></div>
<3rdPartyComponent></3rdPartyComponent>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  templateUrl: './my-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-parent.component.scss'],
})
export class MyParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(3rdPartyComponent, { static: false }) view: 3rdPartyComponent;
}
```

To get a click event on a element with the attribute dependency-id I made this hostlistener:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[dependency-id]' })
export class DependencyClickDirective {
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn: any) {
    console.log('button', btn, 'number of clicks:');
  }
}
```

But this hostlistener only works when the MyParentComponent also have a item with the attribute dependency-id. Also I tried to listend to the event when I attached a event on every Htmlelement, but this doesn't work when the element is nested into another component.

I don't like to do that, because it's a code smell. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: how about window:click? as for the directive, put it directly on the 3rdPartyComponent, not the adjacent div

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that `window` or `body` prefix doesn't change any behavior related to the problem